# Updating product with shoppy api

Tags: java, api, post, unirest

I am using the shoppy api, and I need to update a product using the api, I am trying to update the account list, I am able to update the title/desc, I am not able to update the account list, It says on [here](https://shoppy.dev/#/product/update) I need to send an array, and I did that but the shoppy server dies, this is my code, I am using `unirest` for the post requestion.

```
Map<String, String> accs = new HashMap<>();
accs.put("username", "password");
String response =  Unirest.post("https://shoppy.gg/api/v1/products/xxx").queryString("accounts", accs).headers(headers).asString().getBody();
```

printing `response` returns an error page, but when I just update the title, it says my update was successful, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

This is the print from `response`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Be right back.</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            color: #B0BEC5;
            display: table;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 72px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            font-weight: 200;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="title">Be right back.</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```